# How to add views from Stack to LinearLayout?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, textview, stack

This is stack created by me

```
  public Stack<TextView> rod1_stack=new Stack<TextView>();
```

And I have following LinearLayout

```
LinearLayout Layout_rod_1=findViewById(R.id.rod1_layout);
```

I want to add elements from stack to this layout

This is what I'm trying

```
Layout_rod_1.removeAllViews();
Iterator<TextView> iterator = rod1_stack.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    Layout_rod_1.addView((View) iterator);
}
```

But I'm Getting error as

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
>       java.util.AbstractList$SimpleListIterator cannot be cast to android.view.View

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the below code snippet to add the views from the stack to your linear layout.

```
Layout_rod_1.removeAllViews();
Iterator iterator = rod1_stack.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    TextView tv = iterator.next();
    Layout_rod_1.addView(tv);
}
```

Note I have removed TextView and made iterator as generic one.

```
Iterator < TextView> iterator = rod1_stack.iterator();
```

Changed to

```
Iterator iterator = rod1_stack.iterator();
```

Comment: I am getting error when code is used   Incompatible types

Comment: Try type casting the iterator elements.
TextView tv = (TextView)iterator.next();